# div background only appears during jQuery slide animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm currently building this site:
http://hissvard.altervista.org/3DHC/index.php
The "Iscriviti" button in the page triggers a slide animation, showing another div containing the signup form.
Problem is, this div's background only appears during the animation and becomes transparent after that.
What am I doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/hqqr548m/

```
#signup-container {
    display: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 7px 13px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 7px 13px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 7px 13px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Provide your js/css using jsfiddle.com

Comment: Done, thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set the background image before de animation?

```
 $('#signup-toggle').click(function() {
    $('#signup-container').css('background-image', 'url(http://hissvard.altervista.org/3DHC/images/bg.jpg )')
        $('#signup-container').slideToggle('slow');

        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#signup-container').offset().top }, 'slow');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the event to set

```
display:table;
```

instead of

```
display: block;
```

when click the button for `#signup-container`. child div overflow the parent's div because take his height as zero.